# Python - Extract Text

Tags: python, text, extract

I have a file with some text in it, and there are two values I need to pull from that file and assign to variables.

The first section looks like this:

```
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>4
<SEQUENCE>1
<FILENAME>form.xml
<DESCRIPTION>PRIMARY DOCUMENT
```

Basically I need to pull "form.xml" and assign that to some variable.

The next is like this:

```
<rptOwnerId>0001720314</rptOwnerId>
```

In this case, I need to take the values between the tags and assign it to a variable.

But I'm having difficulty finding the best way to do this.

Thanks all!

Comment: Did you find the second-best way?

Comment: What's wrong with XML parsers? There're built-in and plenty of third-party.

Comment: Can you please provide the entire content of the file in a single block?

Comment: @a11apurva That shouldn't be necessary. It isn't even desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
xml = "<rptOwnerId>0001720314</rptOwnerId>".strip()
value = ET.fromstring(xml).find("rptOwnerId")
if value:
    print(value.text)
```

Hope this helps. I would also recommend you check this article for understanding XML Parsing from scratch [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/parsing-xml-files-in-python-d7c136bb9aa5)